# Script1006 error internet explorer

Tags: jquery

I get a script1006 error with Internet Explorer on the following code:

```
function scroll(top = 0) {
    $('html,body').add('html,body', window.parent.document).animate({scrollTop: top}, "slow");
}
```

It does work on Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Seems to be solved with: 'use strict';

function scroll() {
 var top = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : 0;

 $('html,body').add('html,body', window.parent.document).animate({ scrollTop: top }, "slow");
}

Comment: IE does not like default value : "top = 0"